# How to get a particular Component of a JSplitPane?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

The idea would be to get a particular component of a JSplitPane, for example :

```
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, panel1, panel2);
```

Is there a way to get `panel1` or `panel2` from the Object `splitPane` ?

Comment: Did you try `getLeftComponent()` etc.?

Comment: You might find an answer in the [JSplitPane documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html).

Comment: `You might find an answer... ` - not "might". You "will"...

Comment: What *exactly* DYM by 'get'?  The code already seems to have a *reference* to both panels added to the split pane (`panel1` & `panel2`).  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of all components inside a container (JSplitPane is a container) :

```
    // 2 JPanels for example
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setName("pan1");
    getContentPane().add(panel1);
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setName("pan2");
    getContentPane().add(panel2);

    // creating the JSplitPane container with those panels
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, panel1, panel2);

    // get all components from the JSplitPane and print their names
    Component[] components=splitPane.getComponents();
    for(Component c:components){
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
```